# Magento 2 Multi Server Cron Setup

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, aws, amazon-web-services

If you're running Magento 2 in a cluster, it is recommended to identify a master node that is responsible for the cronjob(see devdocs). Is there some best practice to determine the master node or is it smarter to add another node handling the crons and nothing else? Like a worker instance.

Comment: you can run magento cron from any place. just setup on some server.